# Rails - Add a button that goes to a user's default email with an address in place

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ipad

I'm building an app and wish to allow users to provide continuous feedback while they demo it.  I want to add a "feedback" button to the address bar that will take an iPad user directly to their default email with my team's support box already in the address.  Maybe even some info about the site they are on in the body of the email.  Any tips on where to get started?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto or http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MailLinks.html

Comment: Is your app a web app? Where does Rails come into play here?